# Do I need React.PureComponent when the component is `connect`ed to react-redux store?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

They say we can improve the performance of React app by using `React.PureComponent` in some cases, because it shallow compares its props before updating the component.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent

On the other hand, `react-redux`'s `mapStateToProps` uses shallow comparison when it decides whether we need to update the component.

https://redux.js.org/faq/reactredux#why-is-my-component-re-rendering-too-often

So, can I say I do not need `React.PureComponent` when its props are from  react-redux `connect`, and it has no state? Or is there any difference between them?

Comment: You obviously can benefit from PureComponent if the component uses local state as well.

Comment: Ok, I wanna know given it has no state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your component receives all its props from Redux and all changes to state can be recognized with a shallow comparison, you can use regular Component to the same effect as PureComponent. Just make sure when you update the state you don't mutate it, but instead return a new copy of the state. [Immutable.JS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js) is extremely helpful for this.